# Insert an element in la list by index without moving others

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, insert, append

I want to add elements to an empty list by index. For instance I want to add 4 to the 5th place of list a.

```
x = 4
a = []
```

in other languages like C++ I could create an array with 10 indices and all empty at first and then write something like:

```
a[5] = 4
```

But I could not find the same in python. I just found insert method which moves the next elements one index in every insertion (right?). This I must really avoid.

Maybe I need to remove one element and then insert another element, I don't know. I really appreciate your help, I am really stuck here.

Comment: You would have to pre-allocate the list. Try `a = [None] * 5`, and then you should be able to add values in that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jakub stated, you can pre-allocate your list with values.

```
a = [None] * 5
```

Then, simply use python's list index notation to change an element's value.

```
a[3] = 31
```

Comment: Thanks a million guys :)

Answer (score 3):

If you like Numpy way of doing it, you can use the following

```
import numpy as np
a= np.empty(5)
```

Then, you can assign values normally.

```
a[0]=4
```

Then you can convert this array into a list using

```
a= a.tolist()
```